# Error. ServiceToo.startPlay()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, media-player

I placed my buttons for stop, play and pause in the Bound Service.  When I click the play btn in the MainActivity the app crash with an ServiceToo.startPlay()' on a null object reference.

How can I have access to control my player without it crashing.

```
  **This is the media player in the onCreate.in the Bound Service**

    public void onCreate() {
    mManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    buildNote();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    songlist = new String[]
            {"android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.blipotron,
                    "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + 
R.raw.funk_game,
                    "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + 
R.raw.poofy_reel};


    tracks[0] = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + 
R.raw.blipotron;
    tracks[1] = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + 
R.raw.funk_game;
    tracks[2] = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + 
R.raw.poofy_reel;
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), 
Uri.parse(tracks[currentTrack]));
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    //container = STARTED;
    //mediaPlayer.start();

    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

**This is the buttons methods that are created in the Bound Service**

```
 public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
         //mp.release();
        if (currentTrack < tracks.length -currentTrack) {
            currentTrack++;
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse(tracks[currentTrack]));
            mp.setOnCompletionListener(this);
            mp.start();
        }
    }

        public void play() {
            if (container == STOPPED) {
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        }

        public void stop() {
            if (container == STARTED){
                mediaPlayer.stop();
            }
        }

        public void pause() {
            if (container == STARTED){
                mediaPlayer.pause();
            }

findViewById(R.id.play_btn).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.stop_btn).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.pause_btn).setOnClickListener(this);
```

**This is the actual onClick buttons in the MainActivity**

```
private AudioService serviceRef;


// On Click button instances
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.play_btn) {
        startService(new Intent(this, AudioService.class));
        serviceRef.play();
    } else if (v.getId() == R.id.stop_btn) {
        stopService(new Intent(this, AudioService.class));
        serviceRef.stop();
    } else if (v.getId() == R.id.pause_btn) {
        stopService(new Intent(this, AudioService.class));
        serviceRef.pause();
    }
```

Comment: Can't see `startPlay` anywhere. Please post the stack trace that causes the crash and indicate the line where the crash originates.

Comment: Hello Xiao it is no matter what click method I create i will get this error Process: com.carolgaylor.nubianbook.services, PID: 2490
11-04 23:13:47.660 2490-2490/com.carolgaylor.nubianbook.services E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.carolgaylor.nubianbook.services.AudioService.play()' on a null object reference
11-04 23:13:47.660 2490-2490/com.carolgaylor.nubianbook.services E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.carolgaylor.nubianbook.services.ServicesActivity.onClick(ServicesActivity.java:57)

Comment: I have methods to the buttons created in the Bound Service.  I have the onClick events arranged in the MainActivity.  Because the Bound service is running my Mediaplayer.  But for whatever reason the buttons all not control the player from the MainActivity without shutting down.

Comment: I sure could use some clarity and assistance because I have been searching for a solution to no avail.

Comment: It looks like you're not initialising `serviceRef`. You'll need to use the `bindService()` method. The relevant documentation can be found at http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html

Comment: Hello Xiao, You are so right.  I went back and added the ServiceConnection and corrected my btn methods. My media player stopped crashing. Thank you so much for responding.